# I want to check date lies between financial year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here I want to check whether date from database lies between financial year or not.

I am using following query to check date but it is working properly for year only. if i want to check according to month and year then i got wrong result.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Payments INNER JOIN Subsciber ON Subsciber.SubId = Payments.SubId 
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, Payments.SaveOn) BETWEEN 2010 AND 2011
AND DATEPART(MONTH, Payments.SaveOn) BETWEEN 4 AND 3
```

Comment: Do you not think you could have simplified your example? Fundamentally, you're trying to compare a single date from the `Payments` table against two fixed points in time. Instead, you give us a massive query where the details are obscured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
payments.saveon >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '20100401', 112) AND 
payments.saveon < CONVERT(DATETIME, '20110401', 112)
```